# How to pass environment variables to pytest

Tags: pytest

Before I start executing the tests in my Python project, I read some environment variables and set some variables with these values read. My tests will run on the desired environment based on these values read.

For eg: Let's say the environment variables are called `ENV_NAME` and `ENV_NUMBER`

Now, I would like to run the tests using py.test.

If I hard code these environment variables, for eg: `ENV_NAME = 'staging', ENV_NUMBER = '5'` in my code and then run the tests by executing the py.test command at the root of the project directory, all the tests run successfully.

But, I don't want to hardcode these values. Is there a way, I can send these environment variables as command line arguments for py.test?

I was thinking more in the lines of

```py
py.test -ENV_NAME='staging' -ENV_NUMBER='5'.
```

But, this is not working.

Comment: This is a similar question that may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54900785/how-to-pass-an-environment-variable-in-command-line-to-pytest-to-test-a-function/55054556#55054556

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I finally found the answer i was looking for.

we can set the environment variables like this before running tests using py.test

`ENV_NAME='staging' ENV_NUMBER='5' py.test`

Comment: What a solution, to set environment variables, set environment variables. Was hoping for a real solution …

Answer (score 158):

Another alternative is to use the [pytest-env](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-env/) plugin. It can be configured like so:

```
[pytest]
env = 
    HOME=~/tmp
    D:RUN_ENV=test
```

the `D:` prefix allows setting a default value, and not override existing variables passed to `py.test`.

**Note**: you can explicitly run pytest with a custom config, if you only sometimes need to run a specialized environment set up:

```
pytest -c custom_pytest.ini
```

---

If you use **PyCharm vs pytest-dotenv**, [this](https://github.com/namgivu/pytest-start/pull/1) may be helpful

Comment: Using [pytest-dotenv](https://github.com/quiqua/pytest-dotenv) successfully took the environment variables defined in my .env file and made them available when running `pytest`.

Comment: pytest-env looks defunct, while [python-dotenv](https://github.com/theskumar/python-dotenv) is still active.

Comment: @sourcream are you experiencing any issues using pytest-env, or just noticed it's not been updated for a while (wow for 5 years)? python-dotenv has a slightly different set of use cases; I'd love to hear how you use to update env vars with pytest 

Comment: @tutuDajuju It was just an alert to the newcomer (like me), since this answer is so highly voted. I've never used pytest-env (but I've considered for a while). Right now I'm setting my env vars as prescribed by python-dotenv. I have a .env file in the root directory, and in the test modules that need to use those variables I call  `load_dotenv()`.

Comment: It [looks like](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-env/#history) pytest-env was updated to add type hints in Oct 2022.

Answer (score 53):

In addition to other answers. There is an option to overwrite `pytest_generate_tests` in `conftest.py` and set ENV variables there.

For example, add following into `conftest.py`:

```py
import os

def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    os.environ['TEST_NAME'] = 'My super test name| Python version {}'.format(python_version)
```

This code will allow you to grab `TEST_NAME` ENV variable in your tests application. Also you could make a fixture:

```py
import os
import pytest

@pytest.fixture
def the_name():
    return os.environ.get('TEST_NAME')
```

Also, this ENV variable will be available in your application.

Comment: In conftest.py, you don't even have to use pytest_generate_tests; you can simply set os.environ.

Answer (score 20):

1. I use monkey patch when I don't load environment variable variable outside function.

```py
import os

# success.py
def hello_world():
    return os.environ["HELLO"]

# fail.py
global_ref = os.environ["HELLO"] # KeyError occurs this line because getting environment variable before monkeypatching

def hello_world():
    return global_ref

# test.py
def test_hello_world(monkeypatch):
    # Setup
    envs = {
        'HELLO': 'world'
    }
    monkeypatch.setattr(os, 'environ', envs)

    # Test
    result = hello_world()

    # Verify
    assert(result == 'world')
```

2. If you use PyCharm you can set environment variables, `[Run]` -> `[Edit Configuration]` -> `[Defaults]` -> `[py.tests]` -> `[Environment Variables]`

[image]

Comment: For another example of monkeypatch, see: https://aalvarez.me/posts/pytest-tricks-for-better-python-tests/

Answer (score 17):

It is possible to use [autouse fixtures](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.2.x/how-to/fixtures.html#autouse-fixtures-fixtures-you-don-t-have-to-request).

```py
@pytest.fixture(scope="session", autouse=True)
def set_env():
    os.environ["FLAG"] = "1"
```

Comment: Awesome this is definitely the most elegant and idiomatic solution!

Comment: I was adding environment variables by simply having `os.environ['FLAG'] = '1'` at the top of my `conftest.py`, outside of any function. I am curious - what is the benefit of adding it in a pytest fixture function?

Comment: @crabulus_maximus, 
1. Scoped Setup: Fixtures can limit environment changes to specific scopes, preventing side effects across tests.
2. Delayed Execution: The environment setup isn't run until the fixture is invoked, useful for dynamic values or selective test runs.
3. Teardown Logic: Fixtures allow for automatic cleanup, unsetting variables, or restoring states, ensuring isolation between tests.
4. Readability: It signals to others that certain tests depend on these environment setups, improving clarity.
This method enhances control and reliability, especially in extensive test suites.

Comment: I've spent a while figuring out why this didn't reliably work for me, and it was because this changes the actual environment values. The better way to write the fixture is with monkeypatch: https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/monkeypatch.html#monkeypatching-environment-variables

Answer (score 12):

There are few ways you can achieve this

1. If you dont want to use the environment variable , you can use  pytest addoptions as https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/simple.html
2. You can write a wrapper script like this to call enviornment variables

   ```
   import os
   import py
   env_name = os.environ["ENV_NAME"]
   env_no = os.environ["ENV_NUMBER"]
   pytest_args=(env_name,env_no)
   pytest.main('-s' ,pytest_args,test_file.py)
   ```

in test_file.py
you can use

```
   env_n, env_n = pytest.config.getoption('pytest_args')
```

3. Alternate method if you just want to pass the date not set enviornment variable

on command line you can use it as

```
   py.test --testdata ="ENV_NAME:staging,ENV_NUMBER:5"
```

You can use in your test file

```
pytest_params = pytest.config.getoption('testdata')
params = pytest_params.split(":")
param_dict = dict(params[i:i+2] for i in range(0,len(params),2))
env_name = param_dict["ENV_Name"]
```

Comment: Looks like the **1.** is save as **3.**

Comment: Almost !! Except the first one is fixture called from conftest second one is called directly from test.

Comment: @Macintosh_89 could you give more info on technique 2 please?
Would this wrapper be able to conditionally assign env vars to specific tests in a directory?

Comment: @ChrisGuest , do you mean specific test file or tests within a file ? whatever  `args` you pass in `pytest.main('-s' ,pytest_args,test_file.py)`,  should be available in `test_file.py`. If that's not clear could you elaborate on your requirement ?

Answer (score 11):

Following the idea provided by @tutuDajuju using [pytest-env](https://github.com/MobileDynasty/pytest-env) - an alternative would be to write a custom plugin leveraging [pytest_load_initial_conftests](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#_pytest.hookspec.pytest_load_initial_conftests). Might be useful especially when you don't want or can't install external dependencies.

Here's a quick example:

**Project structure**

```
.
├── __init__.py
├── pytest.ini
├── script.py
└── tests
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── plugins
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   └── env_vars.py
    └── test_script.py
```

**script.py**

```py
import os

FOOBAR = os.environ.get("FOOBAR")


def foobar():
    return FOOBAR
```

**test_script.py**

```py
from script import foobar


def test_foobar():
    assert foobar() == "foobar"
```

**pytest.ini**

```
[pytest]
addopts = -p tests.plugins.env_vars
```

**env_vars.py**

```py
import os

import pytest


@pytest.hookimpl(tryfirst=True)
def pytest_load_initial_conftests(args, early_config, parser):
    os.environ["FOOBAR"] = "foobar"
```

Example run:

```
$ python -m pytest tests -v
========= test session starts =========
platform darwin -- Python 3.8.1, pytest-5.4.1, py-1.8.1, pluggy-0.13.1 -- 
rootdir: /Users/user/pytest_plugins, inifile: pytest.ini
collected 1 item

tests/test_script.py::test_foobar PASSED                                                                                               [100%]

========= 1 passed in 0.01s =========
```

Answer (score 8):

Run `export` inside a subshell (enclosing parenthesis) not to mess up local environment. Supply export with parameters from `.env` file.

`(export $(xargs < .env); pytest -svvvx api)`

Answer (score 6):

Similar to bad_coder had mentioned, you can do:

```py
# test.py
def test_hello_world(monkeypatch):
    # Setup
    monkeypatch.setenv('HELLO', 'world')

    # Test
    result = hello_world()

    # Verify
    assert(result == 'world')
```

Comment: Totally seems like the right answer but, just didn't work for me, and I can't work out why.

Comment: @JohnMee If you need the environment variables at import time, that might be the reason why monkeypatching fails

Comment: This is the way of doing it, and pytest documentation takes a tiny bit further creating fixtures out of this. https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/monkeypatch.html#monkeypatching-environment-variables

Answer (score 3):

I needed to create a `pytest.ini` file **and** pass the environment variables to the `pytest` command. E.g:

In the pytest.ini file I set an empty value because it is overwritten by whatever you pass to the command line command:

```
[pytest]
MY_ENV_VAR=
```

Command line, with the actual value set:

```
$ MY_ENV_VAR=something pytest -c pytest.ini -s tests/**
```

I don't know why does it work like this. I just found out that it works as a result of mere trial and error, because the other answers didn't help me.

Comment: @Acumenus As you say, it _seems_. But the actuality is other, since removing the entry in `pytest.ini` will cause the CLI env var to be ignored.

Comment: The environment variable as it is defined on the CLI will be available to the entire Python process, and nothing about it is pytest specific. For the sake of argument, consider `$ FOO=bar python -c 'import os; print(os.environ["FOO"])'`. If the CLI env var is being ignored, then your application must not be accessing it as an env var, but in some other way.

Comment: @Acumenus My answer is pytest specific. What you say is all correct in theory but, as I explained in my answer, I don't know why pytest will need that workaround, regarding the env vars, but it _does_ need that workaround.

Comment: I had the same issue as you. I created a simple shell script `run-test.sh` in my test directory.
It contains the following one-liner:
`ENV_VAR_NAME_1="env_var_value_1" ENV_VAR_NAME_2="env_var_value_2" pytest -c path/to/pytest.ini path/to/test/`

It's essential to have it on one line; otherwise, the environment variable won't be loaded by pytest.
Enable the shell script execution with `chmod +x run-test.sh`.
You can now run your pytest tests by running `./run-test.sh`.

Answer (score 1):

Although the other answer works I think this one is more  "hands-off" and automated and it simulates normal operation more. So I use `python-dotenv` to load all variables form a file with `load_dotenv(my_filepath)`:

```py
import os
import pytest
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from core import ConfigService


def test_config_service():
    """This test ensures that the config service can read the environment
    variables which define the location of the config.json files"""

    load_dotenv("env/common.env")
    config_service = ConfigService()
    config_service.load()
    assert config_service.config_folder_path is not None
    assert config_service.config_folder_name is not None
```

I think it is better if you want to test your whole logic of:

- Reading the variable from an `.env` file in a specific location and
- Checking to see if the code you are testing is performing as expected based on the values in that file (maybe you could catch typos or other problems with your logic)

Comment: I believe this is only good if you have static variables that load at the time of execution. If, however, you want to pass and interact with variables passed from terminal / command line arguments then I believe you'd need an approach like: `def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption('--remote', action='store', default='False', help='run ui tests remotely')` in a `conftest.py` file.

Comment: Environment variables for testing must be static. Make a test for each permutation, otherwise it ain't testing with proper coverage.

Comment: @CanH.Tartanoglu I have a .env file with common environment variables used in all environments, this way I test if they are read in correctly and also validate their values. I dont understand what you mean they have to be static. Also there are no permutations. I miss something here?

Comment: You can't use your own environment variables for testing and call it testing with full coverage. You need to test with EVERY acceptable value for ALL environment variables used by your application (there are some exceptions to this rule). Assuming you want testing with full coverage, which every developer should strive for. Meaning I wouldn't use the `dotenv` method either, but your critique was alarming to me.

Comment: But no. I set the environment variables. The values in my .env are what their values are. If they ever change they will change from that very file that is the whole point no? Where would these wild environment variable values will come from? Centrally managing and testing environment variable is the whole point.

Comment: Obviously I am not refering to constant environment variables such as file or directory paths, but logical environment variables such as booleans and integers. But why have a `.env` file just for testing when you could just define the variables inside pytest?

Comment: @CanH.Tartanoglu but that is what I describe here. I named the file `common` cause they are common in all environments and if they change I want them to change from that very file, so I have control over them. So different cases really.

Comment: It is an unjustified additional layer of complexity.

Comment: @CanH.Tartanoglu that is a very personal judgement without taking into account the purpose of what we are doing there. But each one to their own.

Comment: Sad to hear that, I tried to be constructive without emotional judgement. Please read my comments again, cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using [pytest-dotenv](https://github.com/quiqua/pytest-dotenv) plugin to load `.env` file and it works pretty well. You can mention multiple env files in your `pytest.ini` like this.

```
[pytest]
env_files =
    .env
    .test.env
    .deploy.env
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using some conftest.py files and need to define different values to one environment variable, you can use the monkeypatch like this:

```
# tests/conftest.py
import pytest
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def env_setup(monkeypatch):
    monkeypatch.setenv("ENVIRONMENT", "local")
```

The `autouse=True` allow you use this fixture in your tests that localized in the same conftest's folder without add manually.

Example:

```
# tests/my_test.py
import os

def is_local_env():
    if os.getenv("ENVIRONMENT") == "local":
        return True
    return False

def test_if_is_local_env():
    result = is_local_env()
    assert result is True
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just patch environment variables `os.environ` using `patch.dict`.

For your sepecific case, to patch env vars before tests execution, you can place the following code in `conftest.py`:

```
from unittest.mock import patch
patch.dict(os.environ, {"ENV_NAME": "staging", "ENV_NUMBER": "5"}).start()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [monkeypatching](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/how-to/monkeypatch.html#monkeypatching-environment-variables), which is bundled with `pytest` when your environment variables are dynamic.