# Setup environment for pre-commit

Tags: python-3.x, pytest, pre-commit-hook, pre-commit.com

How can I source a bash script that contains exports for environment variables?

`env.sh`

```
...
export VARIABLE=test
...
```

`test_file.py`

```
...
os.environ['VARIABLE'] # Throws KeyError
...
```

How can I use pre-commit to run `env.sh` to setup an environment that the following `pytest` hook can use?

```
-   repo: local
    hooks:
    -   id: tests
        name: run tests
        entry: pytest -v
        language: system
        types: [python]
```

Comment: `entry: source env.sh && pytest -v`?

Comment: @hoefling Fails: `Executable 'source' not found`

Comment: What about `entry: . env.sh && pytest -v`?

Comment: @hoefling Same as before, and if I do `entry: sh env.sh && pytest -v` the commit passes but no tests run

Comment: I don't know what the underlying system is (and what tool is the configuration from), but another wild guess - `entry: sh -c ". env.sh && pytest -v"`

Comment: `pre-commit` itself doesn't use shells at all, but you can use `entry: bash -c '...'` or `entry: sh -c '...'` -- another option is to look at [pytest-env](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-env/)

Answer (score 1):

pre-commit-config

- change language to python (optional, but it's so that pre-commit creates a venv)
- entry - we will invoke a bash script instead of invoking pytest directly

Ex.

```
 - repo: local
   hooks:
   - id: tests
     name: run tests
     entry: bash tests.sh
     language: python
```

tests.sh

```
source env.sh
pytest -v .
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use pre-commit for pytest due to:

- tests are often slow, committing should be fast
- It would have to be a system / script hook since you'd need repository specific dependencies.

Source: https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit-hooks/issues/291

I think this will solve your problem: [How to pass environment variables to pytest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36141024/how-to-pass-environment-variables-to-pytest)