# How to test dockerized flask app using Pytest?

Tags: python, docker, flask, pytest

I've built the flask app that designed to run inside docker container. It will
accept POST HTTP Methods and return appropriate JSON response if the header key matched with the key that I put inside [docker-compose `environment`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/).

```
...
    environment:
      - SECRET_KEY=fakekey123
...
```

The problem is: when it comes to testing. The `app` or the `client` fixture of
flask (pytest) of course can't find the docker-compose `environment`. Cause the app didn't start from docker-compose but from pytest.

```py
secret_key = os.environ.get("SECRET_KEY") 
# ^^ the key loaded to OS env by docker-compose
post_key = headers.get("X-Secret-Key")
...

if post_key == secret_key:
    RETURN APPROPRIATE RESPONSE
       .....
```

What is the (best/recommended) approach to this problem?

I find some plugins
[one](https://github.com/pytest-docker-compose/pytest-docker-compose),
[two](https://github.com/AndreLouisCaron/pytest-docker),
[three](https://github.com/lovelysystems/lovely-pytest-docker) to do this. But I asked here if there is any more "simple"/"common" approach. Cause I also want to automate this test using CI/CD tools.

Comment: In my case I would populate then environment in my test case (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36141024)).

Comment: Tried, work great. Thanks. Never heard of pytest-env before. Added to my list after `mocking`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My current solution is to mock the function that read the OS environment. OS ENV is loaded if the app started using docker. In order to make it easy for the test, I just mock that function.

```py
   def fake_secret_key(self):
        return "ffakefake11"

    def test_app(self, client):
        app.secret_key = self.fake_secret_key
        # ^^ real func   ^^ fake func
```

Or another alternative is using [pytest-env](https://github.com/MobileDynasty/pytest-env) as @bufh suggested in comment.

Create `pytest.ini` file, then put:

```py
[pytest]
env =
    APP_KEY=ffakefake11
```

Answer (score 5):

You most likely need to run `py.test` from inside of your container. If you are running locally, then there's going to be a conflict between what your host machine is seeing and what your container is seeing.

So option #1 would be to using `docker exec`:

```sh
$ docker exec -it $containerid py.test
```

Then option #2 would be to create a script or task in your `setup.py` so that you can run a simpler command like:

```sh
$ python setup.py test
```