# How do I pass an argument via command line to set an environ in Python

Tags: python, operating-system, pytest

I'm using python 3.7 and os library. I have to run a battery of tests on both STAGE and TEST environments. Currently the code sets the environment to STAGE

> ENVIRONMENT = os.getenv('ENV', 'STAGE')

but I want it to be set by passing an argument via command line. Anyone?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read/process command line arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009860/how-to-read-process-command-line-arguments)

Comment: It doesn't set it to `STAGE`, it is **defaulting** to `STAGE` if you have not set `ENV` to anything. See [`os.getenv(...)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.getenv)

Comment: How are you running the code? From the commandline or from python itself? What I mean by "python" is, are you having to use the subprocess module to run the script?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36141024/how-to-pass-environment-variables-to-pytest

Answer (score 16):

In case of a command line of a UNIX shell you can set the env variable as part of your command:

`$ ENV=STAGE pytest ./tests/`

Comment: This depends on OS, shell, and whether or not OP is running the script from python or from the command line

Comment: @smac89 You are absolutely correct. I took a stab in the dark and showed one way for a particular system. Answer edited.

Comment: This works of OSX 12.6.2

Answer (score 1):

Setting the environment variable of liking is rather simple, giving the name and the value for a single environmental variable would be something along these lines:

**Using the command line**

```
import os
import sys

var_name = sys.argv[1]
var_value = sys.argv[2]

os.environ[var_name] = var_value
```

Just execute your script from the command line as:

```
my.script ENV STAGE
```

This can be verified as follows within python:

```
var_name in os.environ #python3
os.environ.has_key(var_name) #python2
```

**Interactively**

Using a while construct in the script

```
import os

while True:

    env_var = input("Enter ENV (name:value), type 'done' to exit: ")) #enter var:value

    if env_var.lower() == "done":

        break

    try:

        var, val = env_var.split(":")

    except:

        print ("Wrong input format! name:value required.")

        continue

    os.setenv[var] = val
```

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. OP is asking about environment variables not command line arguments

Comment: @smac89 are you sure? OP said _I want it [the environment variable] to be set by passing an **argument via command line**_. IMHO this answer **is** an answer to the OPs question.

Comment: @jofrev, there is a difference between **_setting environment variable on the command line_** for a program and passing **_command line arguments_** to a program, see the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58593432/2089675) for one of the ways to do so in a UNIX environment

Comment: @smac89, I agree with there being a difference between those two things. Maybe I'm missing something but in my understanding what the OP wanted to do is to pass some arguments to a python program/script and modify the environment according to them. Isn't this what the original answer did?

Comment: @jofrev it makes a difference which you use, because only one of them will populate [`os.environ`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/os.html#os.environ) with the right value for a given environment variable name. This answer is doing it manually by asking the user for the value via the command line arguments, and then manually populating the environment variables. Also OP is asking to be able to do `ENVIRONMENT = os.getenv('ENV', 'STAGE')`, and get the value for the `ENV` variable, not asking the user for a value

Comment: @jofrev I get the confusion, but my point is that passing something via command line is not restricted to just command line _arguments_ and depending on that you want to pass (in this case environmental variables), command line arguments are not the way to go about it. Sure you can do it with command line arguments (as this answer shows), but you are simply reinventing the already available mechanism for doing so

Comment: @smac89 I guess we were then just coming from a different interpretation/assumption of what the OP (actually) wanted. Thanks for clarifying your point of view!!

Answer (score 0):

After "python myfile.py", just type the parameters delimited by spaces, and in the code, you can do the following:

```
import sys

nameOfScript = sys.argv[0]
commandLineArgs = sys.argv[1:]
commandLineArgsAsStr = str(sys.argv)
numArgs = len(sys.argv)
```

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. OP is asking about environment variables not command line arguments

Comment: I II am looking for command Lin args.