# How to add env variable to pytest

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, environment-variables, pytest

I am trying to add env variables to pytest. I have successfully managed to add env and configure for regular python scripts but i am unable to use env vars for pytest.

```
 somefile.env 
 KEY = "12345"

 Config.py
 import os
 headers = {"Key": os.environ.get("KEY"), "content_Type": "application/json"}
```

Above are the values given in .env and config file. I can access headers value in python script, but i am unable to access this header value inside pytest. Eg this is my code in pytest

```
 import os
 from config import headers

  print(headers) #---> as this works as expected and prints key value

  #Pytests starts
  def test_one():
  print(headers) # prints key as None
```

When i call headers in pytest i am getting key value as None

Comment: Can you update your question and add the code that you've tried? I mean you can access environment variables through `os` module in Python: `os.environ.get("CUSTOM_ENV_VARIABLE")` What seems to be the problem then?

Comment: updated question

Comment: I think you can add them in a `pytest.ini` file.

Comment: Tried it but no luck. Entered the following code in pytest.ini
[pytest]
env =
    HOME=~/tmp
    RUN_ENV=1234 

as1234 is my key. I am not sure if i am doing it in right way

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass environment variables to pytest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36141024/how-to-pass-environment-variables-to-pytest)

Comment: none of the approaches are working

Answer (score 8):

The solution here is as described by @user29496

```
# contents of pytest.ini
[pytest]
env =
    D:RUN_ENV=1234
```

This will silently fail/not work unless you install pytest-env

```
pip install pytest-env
```

At this point, the `RUN_ENV` should be correctly passed. See also [How to pass environment variables to pytest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36141024/how-to-pass-environment-variables-to-pytest)

Comment: Hi,
I have tried above solution and unable to pass/read environment variables. I'm using Pycharm as IDE and Python 3.9 version. Here is what i have tried

     # pytest.ini

        [pytest]
        env =
               D:RUN_ENV=1234

        # testfile.py
           import os
           print(os.environ.get('RUN_ENV'))

When i run the testfile.py I'm getting NONE

Comment: [python-dotenv](https://github.com/theskumar/python-dotenv) is a more active project these days.