# How to configure VS code for pytest with environment variable

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I am trying to debug pytest. I would like to inject an environment variable. Here is how I have set launch.json

```
{
    "type": "python",
    "request": "test",
    "name": "pytest",
    "console": "integratedTerminal",
    "env": {
        "ENV_VAR":"RandomStuff"
    }
},
```

But it seems when I start debugging. I do not see the env variable injected, as a result my test which expects that env variable fails.

Also I notice error

```
Could not load unit test config from launch.json
```

Comment: This is weird, post here as well the piece of code where you consume the variable

Comment: Add this `"purpose": ["debug-test"],` and you might like to use `"envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env",` too

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Could not really figure out how to fix "unit" test debugging with Vscode. But with Pytest one can call tests like `python -m pytest <test file>`(https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/usage.html#cmdline)
That means Vscode can be configured like a module

```
"configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Module",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "module": "pytest",
            "args": ["--headful","--capture=no", "--html=report.html"],
        }
```

This is good enough to do debugging of python tests. Also you can then insert environment variables

```
   "env": {
        "ENV_VAR":"RandomStuff"
    }
```

Comment: Where are you adding the last `env` section?

Comment: you can append it to the configuration. For eg in above example it can go after "args" if you want it at end of all keys...like this


"configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Module",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "module": "pytest",
            "args": ["--headful","--capture=no", "--html=report.html"],
             "env": {
                        "ENV_VAR":"RandomStuff"
                        }
            }

Comment: note that by prepending `"${file}"` to the `args`, the config will only debug tests in the current file

Answer (score 16):

### `pytest-env`

#### Install

Per https://stackoverflow.com/a/39162893/13697228:

```bash
conda install -c conda-forge pytest-env
```

Or:

```bash
pip install pytest-env
```

#### `pytest.ini`

Create `pytest.ini` file in project directory:

```ini
[pytest]
env = 
    ENV_VAR=RandomStuff
```

#### Python

In your code, load environment variables as you normally would:

```py
import os
env_var = os.environ["ENV_VAR"]
```

#### `pytest` / VS Code

Either run:

```bash
pytest
```

(Notice how it says `configfile: pytest.ini`)

> ```py
> C:\Users\sterg\Documents\GitHub\sparks-baird\mp-time-split> pytest
> ==================================== test session starts ===================================== platform win32 -- Python 3.9.12, pytest-7.1.1, pluggy-1.0.0 rootdir:
> C:\Users\sterg\Documents\GitHub\sparks-baird\mp-time-split,
> configfile: pytest.ini plugins: anyio-3.6.1, cov-3.0.0, env-0.6.2
> collecting ...
> ```

Or:

[image]

This only seems to work with breakpoints that have manually been set, I'm guessing some other change is needed to pause on errors.

### Python for VS Code Extension

Apparently [the Python for VS Code extension recognizes a `.env` file automatically](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_environment-variable-definitions-file). E.g.
`.env` file:

```
ENV_VAR=RandomStuff
```

Haven't verified, but I'd assume this has the same behavior as using `pytest-env` with a `pytest.ini` file.

### When all else fails

When I don't feel like dealing with the strange hackery necessary to get VS Code, Anaconda environments, and pytest playing nicely together (and/or forget how I fixed it before), I call my tests manually and run it like a normal script (see below). This may not work with more advanced pytest trickery using fixtures for example. At the end of your Python script, you can add something like:

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    my_first_test()
    my_second_test()
```

and run it in debug mode (`F5`) as normal.

Comment: Thank you for "Apparently the Python for VS Code extension recognizes a .env file automatically"

Comment: Just adding confirmation that using a .env file in the root suffices to provide environment variables for test debugging

Answer (score 5):

VSCode's python extension now has a special way of running the debugger when you are running it on python tests.

You can configure it following [this guide](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/testing#_configure-tests). In a nutshell:

- Install the python extension
- Type command `Python: Configure Tests` in the  command palette
- Choose your testing framework (only `pytest` or `unittest` at the moment)
- Create a config in your `.vscode/launch.json` file with your necessary envs:

```
{
    "name": "Python: Tests in current file",
    "purpose": ["debug-test"],
    "type": "python",
    "request": "launch",
    "program": "${file}",
    "args": ["--color=yes"],
    "env": {"ENV_VAR":"RandomStuff"},
    "console": "integratedTerminal",
    "justMyCode": false
}
```

^ the `"purpose": ["debug-test"]` is important, this is how VSCode will know this config is used for debugging tests.

- To debug the tests, run command `Test: Debug Tests in Current File` (or `Test: Debug Test at Cursor`) in the command palette

Advantage v/s the "module" method: not sure there is really one. Well you get a dedicated VS Code shortcut for debugging tests in current file (`cmd ;` + `cmd f`).

EDIT: after trying it out, I wouldn't recommend the `Test: Debug Test at Cursor` command, as it seems to mess up with the tear down (in my case it was preventing the emptying of the test DB)

Comment: this `"purpose": [ "debug-test" ]` does the trick, but does  anyone know how to configure running test `WITHOUT debug` this way? I mean - it works with debug, but every now and then I also need to run the tests without debug, and there is apparently no "purpose" for that.

Answer (score 4):

This works in v 1.72.2

- Create in the workspace folder:

  - .vscode/launch.json
- Similar to the OP, but using "module"

```json
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Pytest",
      "type": "python",
      "request": "launch",
      "module": "pytest",
      "console": "integratedTerminal",
      "env": {
        "testy": "someval"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

- Try some breakpoints (either in test files or app code)
- Start the debugger

[image]

- Watch the `os.environ['testy']` value (must `import os` where the breakpoint is of course)

[image]