# os.environ variables in Jenkins are returning None

Tags: python, jenkins, environment-variables, pytest

I'm confused as to why Jenkins is not recognizing my environment variables.

I have a String parameter named `VAR_TEST` set in the General section of my Jenkins job's /configure screen.  I've included `env` in the Build shell and I see that `VAR_TEST` is listed as an environment variable in the console output, but then when my python code runs, `None` is returned.

I've tried .ini, .env, and Jenkinsfiles as suggested in related SO questions, but no luck.  I've also tried a few Jenkins plugins but no luck.

Python code:

```
variable_test = os.getenv['VAR_TEST']
```

Jenkins console:

```
JENKINS_HOME=/opt/bitnami/apps/jenkins/jenkins_home
VAR_TEST=1,164,169
MAIL=/var/mail/tomcat
SASL_CONF_PATH=/opt/bitnami/common/etc
LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
GIT_TEMPLATE_DIR=/opt/bitnami/git/share/git-core/templates
USER=tomcat
CI=true
...
{blah blah blah}
...
WORKSPACE_TMP=/opt/bitnami/apps/jenkins/jenkins_home/workspace/MY_PROJECT@tmp
+ sudo pytest -m login --headless --junit-xml=report.xml --html=index.html --maximize-window --save-screenshot --env=qa
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux -- Python 3.9.0, pytest-6.2.3, py-1.10.0, pluggy-0.13.1
rootdir: /opt/bitnami/apps/jenkins/jenkins_home/workspace/MY_PROJECT
plugins: xdist-2.2.1, forked-1.3.0, seleniumbase-1.61.0, ordering-0.6, html-2.0.1, metadata-1.11.0, rerunfailures-9.1.1
collected 108 items / 2 errors / 81 deselected / 25 selected

==================================== ERRORS ====================================
_ ERROR collecting my_stuff/tests/test_stuff/test_env_variables_so.py _
my_stuff/tests/test_stuff/test_env_variables_so.py:21: in <module>
    var_test = os.getenv('VAR_TEST').split(",")
E   AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
```

When I run this code locally in PyCharm, I simply list the Environment Variables in the Edit Configurations... view and the code runs without problem.  However, it is not running in Jenkins.

Comment: you need to `export` the variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37396406/6321777

Set the env vars BEFORE `pytest`

Example:
`FOO=$FOO pytest -m test_foo`

Comment: ahah - that makes sense - sorry, I didn't spot the `pytest` tag in your original question! I'd recommend marking this as the Answer and also marking your Question as a duplicate

Answer (score 1):

before running your script, you need to `export` the variables so other shells can find 'em

```sh
FOO="bar"
export FOO
```

or the vaguely-less-execution-safe, but more typo-safe single line
([Why not to export variables on the same line you assign them?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/438236/why-not-to-export-variables-on-the-same-line-you-assign-them))

```sh
export FOO="bar"
```

Comment: that (FOO="bar" --> export FOO) fixes the problem when I execute the test via command line locally ... but the error mentioned above persists when executed in Jenkins.

Comment: @rHenderson try `print(os.environ)` to see what Python has available

Comment: POSIX shell explicitly allows for assignments in an `export` statement. I'm not sure what old shells would break on `export FOO="bar"`.

Comment: @chepner it's certainly allowed, I mean unsafe in that it may not behave the way one expects (especially with things like `set-e`), not that it's truly an unsafe use! specifically, `export` on the same line discards the exit code of a contained command and always succeeds (assuming non-pedantic conditions like insufficient system memory) I've added a link in my answer about it!