# How to run a terminal command before running the tests in pytest?

Tags: python, pytest

I have written several tests in pytest. For one of them I need to run the following command in terminal :

```
PATH="$(pwd)/testing/scripting:$PATH"
```

Since I want to run the tests in different machines I wanted to automate this process.

Comment: What about using a bash script to set the environment and then run Python?

Comment: As your terminal command is just a modification of an environment variable, one of the answers here might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36141024/how-to-pass-environment-variables-to-pytest

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use [`conftest.py`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/fixture.html#conftest-py-sharing-fixtures-across-multiple-files)

Something like below:

```
import os

def pytest_sessionstart(session):
    path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'testing/scripting')
    os.environ['PATH'] =  path + os.pathsep + os.environ['PATH']
```