# how to run pytest conftest before everything is imported

Tags: python, django, pytest

This is a simplified version of my problem.

I have a python application with the structure as below:

```
my_project
    my_app
        __init__.py
        settings.py
    tests
        __init__.py
        conftest.py
        my_test.py
     venv
```

```
# settings.py

from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv() 
MY_VALUE = os.environ["MY_KEY"]
```

**I dont want to add a `.env` file in here for some reasons. I also dont want to use get method on `os.environ`**

I want to run this test

```
# my_test.py

from my_app import settings # I need this for some reasons

def test_something():
    assert True

def test_env():
    assert os.environ["MY_KEY"] == 'MY_VALUE'
```

However, I get a `KeyError` because once I import `settings.py`, the line `MY_VALUE = os.environ["MY_KEY"]` is run and because `MY_KEY` is not in env, I get `KeyError`.

What I thought is that I could have conftest as below

```
import os
from unittest import mock

import pytest


@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def set_env(config):
    with mock.patch.dict(os.environ, {'MY_KEY': 'MY_VALUE'}):
        yield
```

But it is still the same problem.

How can I enforce this conftest before everything else.

also note that if I comment out `from my_app import settings` both my tests will pass

NOTE: the reason I do not want to use `os.environ.get("MY_KEY")` is that I want to enforce env variable to exist before the application or the test is initialized. The reason for this is that in reality, when my application is running in a docker container, the env variables are there before everything else and I want to increase dev-prod parity. https://12factor.net/dev-prod-parity

Comment: Why not have the fixture within settings.py itself?

Comment: test should be seperate from applocation. That does not make sense at all

Comment: How about https://github.com/MobileDynasty/pytest-env?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass environment variables to pytest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36141024/how-to-pass-environment-variables-to-pytest)

Comment: it's a global variable that is loaded prior to any patching, you can reload after patching to get proper value

Answer (score 3):

This occurs because pytest first collects all tests and then runs them.

During the collection phase, pytest imports `conftest.py` and `my_test.py`.

During the test running phase, pytest applies fixtures and runs the test functions themselves.

In your case, during the collection phase, `my_test.py` imports `my_app/settings.py`, resulting in the side effect of reading the environment variable `os.environ["MY_KEY"]`. Since fixtures have not been applied yet, a `KeyError` is raised.

There are two ways to resolve this issue:

#### 1. Structure your code without side effects.

Instead of initializing the settings inside the module, the initialization could be moved to the `get_settings` function. Additionally, `functools.cache` can be used to ensure that the configuration is loaded only once.

```py
# my_app/settings.py
import functools
from dotenv import load_dotenv

@functools.cache
def get_settings():
    load_dotenv() 
    MY_VALUE = os.environ["MY_KEY"]
    return {"MY_KEY": MY_VALUE}


# tests/conftest.py
import os
from unittest import mock
import pytest

@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def set_env():
    with mock.patch.dict(os.environ, {'MY_KEY': 'MY_VALUE'}):
        yield

# tests/my_test.py
from my_app import get_setting


def test_env():
    settings = get_setting()
    assert settings["MY_KEY"] == 'MY_VALUE'
```

#### 2. Lazy import of `settings.py`

If the first point is not applicable, `settings.py` could be imported inside a test. This way, it will be imported in the test run phase, after the fixture has been applied.

```py
# my_app/settings.py
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv() 
MY_VALUE = os.environ["MY_KEY"]


# tests/conftest.py
import os
from unittest import mock
import pytest

@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def set_env():
    with mock.patch.dict(os.environ, {'MY_KEY': 'MY_VALUE'}):
        yield

# tests/my_test.py
def test_env():
    from my_app import settings
    
    assert settings.MY_KEY == 'MY_VALUE'
```

Note that Python will cache the settings after the first import. If you want to run multiple tests with different settings, you could:

```py
# tests/conftest.py
import os
import importlib
from unittest import mock
import pytest

@pytest.fixture
def set_env_1():
    with mock.patch.dict(os.environ, {'MY_KEY': 'MY_VALUE_1'}):
        yield

@pytest.fixture
def set_env_2():
    with mock.patch.dict(os.environ, {'MY_KEY': 'MY_VALUE_2'}):
        yield

@pytest.fixture
def settings():
    from py_helpers import settings
    return importlib.reload(settings)


# tests/my_test.py
def test_env_my_key_1(set_env_1, settings):
    assert settings.MY_KEY == 'MY_VALUE_1'

def test_env_my_key_2(set_env_2, settings):
    assert settings.MY_KEY == 'MY_VALUE_2'
```

Answer (score 1):

When testing apps, your environment variable needs to be created before creating the app.

If you set the env vars after the app has already been created, it will not change the app's environment.

What should work is if you add this to the top of your `conftest.py` file, after imports but before defining fixtures or importing the app.

```
import os

os.environ['MY_KEY'] = 'MY_TEST_VALUE'
```

In your question, because you set the environment variable within a fixture in `conftest.py`, it will only be executed when individual tests are run. By then your app would have already been created, and the execution would have no effect.

source: pytest-flask documentation