# Specify multiple pytest configurations

Tags: python, pytest, python-3.8

I'm using `pytest` to run some tests. Is there a way to specify multiple configurations through the **pytest.ini**?

The reason I need this is that when testing a locally running Lambda, I require some slightly different options than when running in CI pipeline.

For example, to check if tests are being run against a locally running Lambda, I check the value of an environment variable `MYFUNCTION_LOCAL` in the `setup_class` method of a test class. Additionally there are options such as `--color no` that don't necessarily need to be included when testing against a locally running Lambda.

Currently my 'pytest.ini' file looks like this. I can't add `MYFUNCTION_LOCAL` because the value will differ depending on where the tests are executed.

```sh
[pytest]
addopts = --color no --capture no --verbose
minversion = 7.0
env =
    AWS_XRAY_SDK_ENABLED=false
```

There seems to be the option of using a TOML file, but the documentation suggests that only the `tool.pytest.ini_options` table is considered at this time, so I don't think that is an option.

What is the best way to handle scenarios like this with `pytest`?

Comment: Do you need to have it in pytest.ini? You can pass it as an argument and accept it in conftest.py to further process it.

Comment: @DevangSanghani, thanks for the comment. I have considered using `pytest_addoption` to set whether or not the tests are being executed locally, but I'm finding that there are several other settings that are environment specific, so I wish to avoid really long CLI commands that have to typed every time I wish to run some tests. For that reason, it would be preferable to somehow configure multiple environments through **pytest.ini**.

Comment: can you elaborate on what you're defining as configuration in this question. I think you can always add options at the command line too to merge with the options found in the ini file, I believe command line arguments take precedence.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass environment variables to pytest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36141024/how-to-pass-environment-variables-to-pytest)

Answer (score 3):

You can create two separate `ini` files, then pass them with the `-c` arg

Quoting `pytest --help`

> -c file
>
> Load configuration from `file` instead of trying to locate one of the implicit configuration files

For example:

- `pytest -c lambda-pytest.ini`
- `pytest -c ci-pytest.ini`