# tox-conda: multiple Python interpreters for tests

Tags: python, conda, tox

All afternoon I've been reading and rereading documentation for [tox](https://tox.wiki/en/latest/config.html) and [tox-conda](https://github.com/tox-dev/tox-conda), [lots](https://cloudcity.io/blog/2018/03/12/multiversion-testing-with-tox/) of [blog](https://www.seanh.cc/2018/09/01/tox-tutorial/#envlist) and [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77018312/pytest-specify-different-environments-for-different-tests) [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57654165/1854821), and I still haven't a clue how to make tox use [Conda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conda_(package_manager)) to test my Python package against multiple Python interpreter versions.

I'm an Earth scientist; I use [Miniforge](https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge) to manage my Python environments because it handles non-Python dependencies (and, for that matter, [R](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R_%28programming_language%29) projects) nicely.  So, I start off by creating a virtual environment to contain the tox/tox-conda setup:

```
mamba create -n sandbox python=3.10 tox-conda
mamba activate sandbox
```

Then I create Conda environments to give tox access to Python 3.10 an 3.11:

```
mamba create -n py311 python=3.11
mamba create -n py310 python=3.10
```

Then I try to test my package against 3.10 and 3.11 by running tox in my Python package directory with this *tox.ini* file:

```
[tox]
requires = tox-conda
envlist = py310, py311
isolated_build = True

[testenv]
deps = pytest
commands =
         pytest
```

It works like a charm for 3.10. I think, because my base environment for tox uses 3.10.  tox can't find the interpreter for 3.11, and I can't work out what to put in tox.ini to point it there.  The error I get is `ERROR: cowardly refusing to delete` envdir `(it does not look like a virtualenv): /home/timh/Code/pgongrid_sandbox/.tox/py311`

I've tried adding `[testenv:py310]` and `[testenv:py311]` sections to tox.ini that use the absolute path to the interpreters (e.g., `$HOME/mambaforge/envs/py311/bin/python3`) or specify python=3.10 or python=3.11 in the `deps` or `conda-deps` settings, but I've not managed to steer tox away from the Python available in the Conda environment I run tox from.

Is there an example *tox.ini* anywhere on the web that does this?  None of the settings in the [tox-conda Usage documentation](https://github.com/tox-dev/tox-conda#usage) seem to fit the bill.

This is on [Ubuntu 20.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_20.04_LTS_(Focal_Fossa)) (Focal Fossa), tox 3.28.0, tox-conda 0.10.2, mamba 1.5.2, and Conda 23.9.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the **conda-deps** setting in your **tox.ini** file. This setting allows you to specify a list of conda packages that should be installed in the Tox environment. You can use this to install the Python interpreter that you want to use for the tests.
For example, the following tox.ini file will create two Tox environments, one for Python 3.10 and one for Python 3.11. The Python interpreter for each environment will be installed from Conda.

```
[tox]
requires = tox-conda
envlist = py310, py311

[testenv]
conda-deps =
    python=3.10
    pytest

[testenv:py311]
conda-deps =
    python=3.11
    pytest
```

Comment: Thanks, @abdul-rauf-mirzayee.  I could swear I tried that yesterday; I must have had some subtle difference.  This works for me with one change: I seem to need to put pytest under deps, not conda-deps, in order for the test environment to find it.  In fact nothing I put under conda-deps seems to get into the testing environment except the specified python.  I'll likely post an issue at tox-conda's github.

Comment: Was this generated by [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned) (or similar)?