# Set env vars for VSCode python testing

Tags: visual-studio-code, environment-variables, pytest, python-unittest

It's common practice to [use VSCode's `launch.json` to set environment variables](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/launch-json-reference#_environment) for running and debugging python. However if I [use VSCode's "Testing" view for python testing](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/testing), is there a way for the pytest or unittest scripts to use one of the configurations in `launch.json` to set env vars? If not, what would be the best way to set them for VSCode's Testing?

`PyTest` has [`pytest-env`](https://github.com/MobileDynasty/pytest-env), however my hope was that VSCode would have a consistent way to handle env vars with python, one that would not require configuration duplication or bespoke code that ties the two.

As I'm using `pytest`, I ended up defining the env vars in `pytest.ini` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39162893/348545), however as before it creates duplication with `launch.json`

Answer (score 1):

I think, you want use your env vars as pytest global vars. You can assign them in the `conftest.py`:

```
def pytest_configure(config):
    pytest.var = os.environ.get("FOO")
```

Advantage of this approach is that you can not only use this variable within the test case, but pass it to the decorators and other fixtures:

```
@pytest.mark.skipif(pytest.var == "foo")
def test_000():
    ...
```

Comment: I'm testing code that relies on env vars, so my goal is to configure the env vars themselves, not just to use them